Task bar view open program and jump
I'm working with multiple monitors using Windows 11, wanting to know how to make the mouse cursor show up in the monitor that has the program I chose in the task bar. What happens now is that say I opened Word files on each monitor and I hover mouse over Word in the task bar and clicked on the Word I needed but my mouse cursor is still in the current monitor not the monitor that has the Word I wanted. Any suggestion?
